# Who gave that Jigglypuff that microphone-marker thing?

Tags: pokemon

I have encountered a Jigglypuff few times in the Pokémon anime. One episode in which alien Pokémons kidnapped Pikachu to power their spaceship showed Jigglypuff. Also, there were several episodes around that episode showing her. I am talking about that Jigglypuff.

[image]

Jigglypuff's singing put every sentient being to sleep (which made me wonder why she isn't the most powerful Pokémon out there) and if that wasn't enough, someone has given her a microphone which can be converted into a marker which angry Jigglypuff can use well. Who gave it to her?

I don't believe a Jigglypuff is born with a microphone. While a microphone could be of evolutionary advantage to a Jigglypuff in survival, I doubt a marker is really required. Also, I can find lots of images of Jigglypuff without a microphone.

[image]

Or, is a Jigglypuff really born with that microphone-marker thing?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In the chapter [EP045 *The Song of Jigglypuff*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EP045).

This "microphone" is a black marker pen with a green lid. Jigglypuff obtained this marker pen when Ash, Brock and Misty fell asleep the first time they heard it sing. It, angry over a perceived lack of attention, rummaged in Ash's backpack and found it.

As part of the answer and for more information, Jigglypuff loses his micro in some chapters but ends up getting it back somehow or another. These chapters are:

- [EP062 *Clefairy Tales*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EP062) - The Clefairy's steal the microphone.
- [EP149 *Tunnel Vision*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EP149) - Snubbull steal the microphone.

Comment: Oh, I just recalled that that thing wasn't a real mic...

Comment: Does this imply that the only Jigglypuff we ever see in the Pokémon universe is the same specific Jigglypuff?

Comment: @Qix yes exactly, is all time the same Jigglypuff.

Comment: Yeah, that adorable pest is even more persistent than Team Rocket